# How to set IgnoreSIGPIPE=no for docker service?

Tags: linux, docker, systemd

I am setting up mesosphere DC/OS on CentOS 7.6 with docker version 18.09.2 While floating containers on the infra I am getting broken pipe error. I am trying to set IgnoreSIGPIPE=no for docker service. I've overriden the IgnoreSIGPIPE value by editing docker.service. But there is one more service named as docker.io.service and I am unable to find that in my system. Can anyone suggest me where to find it or how to set IgnoreSIGPIPE=no correctly on CentOS?
Here is the output of 'docker version' command:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.6
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        481bc77156
 Built:             Sat May  4 02:34:58 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 03:47:25 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Some more outputs:

```
[root@host] systemctl show docker.io.service | grep SIGPIPE
IgnoreSIGPIPE=yes

[root@host] systemctl show docke.service | grep SIGPIPE
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
```